# Problem adding to solr index from Django using zc.buildout

Tags: python, django, solr, buildout, django-haystack

I'm trying to get Apache Solr running inside my zc.buildout environment.

I've defined a simple model:

```
class NewsItem(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=255, help_text=u"Title of this news item")
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=False, help_text=u"Slug will be automatically generated from the title")
    article = models.TextField(help_text=u"The body text of this news item")
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

search_index.py:

```
import datetime
from haystack.indexes import *
from haystack import site
from appname.models import *


class NewsItemIndex(RealTimeSearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return NewsItem.objects.all()


site.register(NewsItem, NewsItemIndex)
```

And a `search_sites.py` defines:

```
import haystack
haystack.autodiscover()
```

The settings file contains:

```
HAYSTACK_SITECONF = 'appname.search_sites'
HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE = 'solr'
HAYSTACK_SOLR_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr'
HAYSTACK_SEARCH_RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 30
HAYSTACK_INCLUDE_SPELLING = True
```

'haystack' is listed in INSTALLED_APPS, pysolr is listed in the 'install_requires' in setup.py (offered by buildout)

My buildout.cfg contains `solr-files`, `solr`, `solr-conf` and `supervisor`.

I've added `${buildout:directory}/solr-conf` to the `[mkdir]` paths.

The supervisor and solr sections in buildout.cfg look like this:

```
[supervisor]
recipe = collective.recipe.supervisor
port = localhost:9001
user = admin
password = admin
plugins =
   superlance

# solr security settings: see
# http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Connectors+slow+to+startup
programs =
   10 solr     (startsecs=10) java [-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -jar start.jar] ${buildout:parts-directory}/solr true

eventlisteners =
   SolrHttpOk TICK_60 ${buildout:bin-directory}/httpok [-p solr -t 20 http://localhost:8983/solr/]


[solr-files]
recipe = hexagonit.recipe.download
url = ftp://mir1.ovh.net/ftp.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/1.3.0/apache-solr-1.3.0.tgz
md5sum = 23774b077598c6440d69016fed5cc810
strip-top-level-dir = true

[solr]
recipe = collective.recipe.solrinstance
solr-location = ${buildout:parts-directory}/solr-files
host = localhost
port = 8983

unique-key = uniqueID
default-search-field = text

index =
   name:uniqueID type:string indexed:true stored:true required:true
   name:text type:string indexed:true stored:true required:false omitnorms:false multivalued:true

[solr-conf]
recipe = iw.recipe.cmd
on_install = true
on_update = true
cmds =
   cp -v ${buildout:directory}/solr-conf/jetty.xml ${solr:jetty-destination}
   cp -v ${buildout:directory}/solr-conf/schema.xml ${solr:schema-destination}
   cp -v ${buildout:directory}/solr-conf/stopwords_fr.txt ${solr:schema-destination}

[solr-rebuild]
recipe = iw.recipe.cmd
on_install = true
on_update = true

# since solr is not started by solr-instance but supervisord, solr-instance has
# no pid file and thinks that solr is down. Thus we must run it with
# solr-instance to be able to "solr-instance purge"
cmds =
   ${buildout:bin-directory}/supervisorctl stop solr
   cp -v ${buildout:directory}/solr-conf/schema.xml ${solr:schema-destination}
   ${buildout:bin-directory}/solr-instance start
   COUNT=15; echo "Waiting $COUNT s"; sleep $COUNT
   ${buildout:bin-directory}/solr-instance purge
   time ${buildout:bin-directory}/${django:control-script} rebuild_index
   ${buildout:bin-directory}/solr-instance stop
   ${buildout:bin-directory}/supervisorctl start solr
```

When I run `$ bin/buildout install solr-rebuild`, I get the following output:

```
`/appname/solr-conf/schema.xml' -> `/appname/parts/solr/solr/conf/schema.xml'
Solr started with pid 16023
Waiting 15 s
SimplePostTool: version 1.2
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Make sure your XML documents are encoded in UTF-8, other encodings are not currently supported
SimplePostTool: POSTing args to http://localhost:8983/solr/update..
SimplePostTool: COMMITting Solr index changes..

WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index.
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y

Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
All documents removed.
Indexing 1 news items.
Failed to add documents to Solr: [Reason: ERROR:unknown field 'django_ct']
0.32user 0.05system 0:02.82elapsed 13%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 57872maxresident)k
160inputs+8outputs (3major+4257minor)pagefaults 0swaps
Solr stopped successfully.
```

Similarly, running `$ bin/django rebuild_index` or `$ bin/buildout update_index` complains about 'django_ct':

`Failed to add documents to Solr: [Reason: ERROR:unknown field 'django_ct']`

(one thing I'm going to try is update solr to the latest version.. will report if that does it..)

I'm not sure where to look next.. Searching google, groups and stackoverflow didn't get me past this point.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

OK, problem solved. Updating to Solr 1.4.1 (and, strangely, rebooting after that) did the trick.